# How to enter values in cells in Excel in a column with VBscript

Tags: vbscript

```
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForReading)
    strAll = Split(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare) 'Gets each line from file
    i = LBound(strAll)
    Do While i < UBound(strAll)
       If (InStr(1, strAll(i), "DAU SNo.-C0", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
          i = i + 4 'Skip 4 lines to get to first SN
          Do Until InStr(1, strAll(i), "+", vbTextCompare) > 0 'Loop until line includes "+"
             strSNO = Split(strAll(i), "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
             'put strSNO into next cell in column A
             **objSheet.Cells.Offset(1,0).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))**
             i = i + 1
          Loop
       End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

This code splits a text file successfully and puts the two values I want in strSNO(1) and strSNO(2). I want to write them into column A row 2 and column B row 2, then put the next value in row 3 in the next iteration of the loop. I tried the offset method and it gave errors. All the help I am finding is for VBA. Can anyone tell me what to put where the code is in bold to fix it?

EDIT:

Solved it.This is what I did:

```
strAll = Split(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare) 'Gets each line from file
    i = LBound(strAll)
    c=2
    Do While i < UBound(strAll)
       If (InStr(1, strAll(i), "DAU SNo.-C0", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
          i = i + 4 'Skip 4 lines to get to first SN
          Do Until InStr(1, strAll(i), "+", vbTextCompare) > 0 'Loop until line includes "+"
            strSNO = Split(strAll(i), "|", -1, vbTextCompare) 
            i = i + 1
            objSheet.Cells(c,1).Offset(1,0).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))
            objSheet.Cells(c,2).Offset(1,0).Value = Trim(strSNO(2))
            c=c+1
            Loop
      End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Note that `objSheet.Cells(c,1).Offset(1,0)` is the same as `objSheet.Cells(c+1,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
objSheet.Cells.Offset(1,0).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))
```

with

```
objSheet.Cells(i,1).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))
objSheet.Cells(i,2).Value = Trim(strSNO(2))
```

**Edit:** Are you certain you want the fields 1 and 2 of `strSNO`? VBScript arrays are 0-based, so the first index is 0, not 1.

To locate an error add some debugging code:

```
On Error Resume Next
objSheet.Cells(i,1).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))
If Err Then
  WScript.Echo i & ": " & strAll(i)
  WScript.Echo "strSNO(1) = " & strSNO(1)
  WScript.Echo "strSNO(1) is of type " & TypeName(strSNO(1))
End If
Err.Clear
objSheet.Cells(i,2).Value = Trim(strSNO(2))
If Err Then
  WScript.Echo i & ": " & strAll(i)
  WScript.Echo "strSNO(2) = " & strSNO(2)
  WScript.Echo "strSNO(2) is of type " & TypeName(strSNO(2))
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

If the problem turns out to be that `strAll(i)` doesn't contain a `|` for some `i`, so the `Split()` produces an array with just one element, you can work around that by something like this:

```
strSNO = Split(strAll(i) & "|", "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: I tried that. It gave me an error pointing to that line: Subscript out of range: `number: 1` But using Msgbox strSNO(1) or Msgbox strSNO(2) worked perfectly, showing the values I wanted in a window at each iteration.

Comment: I verified that strSNO(1) and strSNO(2) contain the values I want by using Msgbox. The is correct and increments to the next line in the text file, proving the parsing is right.